# Cannot send ping request from server-client and vice versa

Tags: server, dns, active-directory, ip-address, windows-server-2012-r2

i had install windows server 2012 r2 in a virtual box
and also installed windows 7 in same virutual box
i configued my client DNS as my server IP address
**ex:**
`server-ip- a.b.c.d
 client-dns - a.b.c.d` 
both system has different class c ip address and
same default gateway
In server DNS i configued as blank ( . . . )
then why i can't ping my server and client

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding NAT network in a virtual Box network setting
**steps:**
In virtual box preferences create a new network..
in both machine's network setting add to the NAT netowork..
Then the both machines will communicate..